# how to convert to a list in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to convert a set to a list in Python I'm using this syntax:

```
maxi = np.max(A)   # maxi = np.ndarray.max(s)
print("max number of s is ", maxi, " .")
index = np.argwhere(A == maxi)
```

However, I get the following stack trace:

```
[[[1, 2]], [[2, 1]]]
```

The result I need is the following:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 1]]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is a question for perhaps stack overflow

Comment: Please show what's contained in your numpy array `A`.

Comment: change your print statement to `print 'Max number of s is ' + str(maxi) + ' .'` for a start

Comment: "I am trying to convert a set to a list in Python" is not at all what the above code is about. `a = {1,2,3}; b = list(a)` would be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have a list,

```
>>> lst = [[[1, 2]], [[2, 1]]]
```

You can check its length and its elements:

```
>>> len(lst)
2
>>> lst[0]
[[1, 2]]
>>> len(lst[0])
1
```

Then a simple list comprehension does what you want

```
>>> [l[0] for l in lst]
[[1, 2], [2, 1]]
```

If what you have is really a numpy array, you can either use the same list comprehension (numpy arrays are python sequences), or use numpy-specific functionality. For instance, `squeeze` removes length-one axes from an array:

```
>>> a = np.array(lst)
>>> a.shape
(2, 1, 2)
>>> a.squeeze()
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 1]])
>>> b = a.squeeze()
>>> b.shape
(2, 2)
>>> b.tolist()
[[1, 2], [2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you have a list of lists, you can use the `chain` function to unpack the inner list like so:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> lst = [[[1, 2]], [[2, 1]]]
>>> chain(*lst)
# [[1, 2]], [[2, 1]]
```